# Java GC not collecting certain Object

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have an issue with my application, and have narrowed it down a little bit. It seems there are unused objects in my memory.

However strangely enough the GC does not collect them (even not when the program is essentially idling, ie. there are no processing threads active), but when I press "Collect Garbage" in the Netbeans IDE's Profiler, it does collect.

I found the code that is responsible for using a high amount of memory temporarily:

```
private Integer getWhiteLines(BufferedImage image) {
    Map<Integer, List<Color>> heightColors = new HashMap<>();

    for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
        List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
            int colorRGBA = image.getRGB(w, h);
            Color color = new Color(colorRGBA, true);
            colors.add(color);
        }
        heightColors.put(h, colors);
    }

    Integer whiteLines = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Color>> entry : heightColors.entrySet()) {
        Color avgColor = avgColor(entry.getValue());
        if (isWhite(avgColor)) {
            whiteLines++;
        }
    }
    return whiteLines;
}
```

It lists the color of every pixel in an image (previously a PDF file).

This issue is also pretty big, as for example on some PDF it happens that the `Color` Object takes up 14MB of memory.

Why would this behavior be occurring and how would I be able to solve it?

Comment: What does avgColor do?

Comment: @arynaq Give the average of all colors by returning a `Color` from a `List<Color>`.

Comment: A simple cure would be to avoid storing all the colors in the first place. When you just need the average, you can compute it on the fly.

Comment: @Henry I'll look into that for sure, I think the code used to be more complex. The real issue though might be in that threads are never automatically garbage collected.

Comment: You've said "I have an issue with my application" but never explained what that issue is. If the issue is that objects aren't garbage collected immediately, *that's not an issue*; it's only an issue when the lack of garbage collection causes other issues, in which case you need to explain what those are.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Is that something we want in general though? I would like my program to grow and shrink with the RAM needed, while not harming other applications that are running in the OS. I don't want that the program waits until its assigned memory is full.

Comment: If the garbage is collected when you press the GC button, then you don't have an issue.

Comment: @skiwi Assuming there are objects eligible to be collected it should happen before the allocated memory has been used in its entirety. However, if you have 100MB allocated for the application, and it's only using 14MB, there's no point in garbage collecting; you have 86MB left to use and the overhead of performing the garbage collection isn't worth it. There are ways to tune garbage collection, but unless it's causing specific issues that seems like an unnecessary waste of time/effort.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist In real life the heap is not uniform and a minor GC will happen as soon as the Eden space is exhausted. Since all OP's Color objects are very short-lived, they should never survive that collection.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My threads, that have the data (also the `Color` objects) associated with them run inside a `ExecutorService`. I believe the `ExecuterService` reuses the threads, so will the thread data ever be ready for garbage collection?

Comment: @skiwi: No. As you're using no `ThreadLocal`, nothing gets pinned by your threads. I guess that's just like said above: It'd be stupid to GC the couple of bytes if there's a lot of free memory.

Comment: @skiwi An object either is or isn't reachable, and that has nothing to do with thread pools. As soon as your method completes, no Color instances are reachable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The GC is not forced to collect memory whensoever, only when you require a memory allocation, and your VM does not have enough resources. You can reduce the footprint this way:

```
private Integer getWhiteLines(BufferedImage image) {
    Integer whiteLines = 0;
    for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
        List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
            int colorRGBA = image.getRGB(w, h);
            Color color = new Color(colorRGBA, true);
            colors.add(color);
        }

        Color avgColor = avgColor(colors);
        if (isWhite(avgColor)) {
            whiteLines++;
        }
    }

    return whiteLines;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious reason for you to be saving the `colors` ArrayList for each row into a Map, then iterating over that separately to calculate the average colour and determine whether it's a white line or not. You can do all of that in a single loop:

```
private Integer getWhiteLines(BufferedImage image) {
    Integer whiteLines = 0;
    for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
        List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
            int colorRGBA = image.getRGB(w, h);
            Color color = new Color(colorRGBA, true);
            colors.add(color);
        }
        Color avgColor = avgColor(colors);
        if (isWhite(avgColor)) {
            whiteLines++;
        }
    }
    return whiteLines;
}
```

That will result in the objects going out of scope earlier (since the `Color` objects are only preserved for each iteration of the outer loop, rather than for the entire execution time of the function), and that memory being available for garbage collection at an earlier point.

However, it's worth noting that the garbage collector won't necessarily run the moment your program is idle. It's not a free process, and as such garbage collection only happens when it's actually needed to free up memory. An Object being eligible for garbage collection doesn't mean its memory will be immediately reclaimed.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Not entirely surprising; there's only one logical way to move around the necessary sections of the code they already had, and I hate using whitespace when there's no need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say when garbage memory will be collected when application is idle. Did you ever get outofmemory exception? Also if application is taking much memory, you can restrict it with -Xms -Xmx JVM arguments.

For tasks of this type, you should consider calculating values on fly when you iterate through input values.

If you can not do on fly, you should consider reusing objects created for first time.